# Azure function running with a python version different than virtual enviroment

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I'm trying to debug my azure function with python in visual studio code. However, when I press F5, I continue to have this problem:

> connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9091

[image]

So I noticed that  my azure function is using python version  3.9.7 but my IDE is using python version  3.8.12 (virtual enviroment) and I have the libraries installed there.

Can someone help me solve this problem please?

I have created a new virtual environment and I tried to assign it to VS code but it does not worked. Also, I try running the function with func host start but I can't debug it.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You can install a python 3.9.7 in local and set that up as virtual environment.

You can do this with Pyenv. Check the below documentations to install pyenv and crate a virtual env with a specified python version.

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/

Alternatively, You can install a specific python version with apt. Check the below post and replace the python version with the one you wish to work on.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/how-do-i-install-a-different-python-version-using-apt-get

This way if you install python 3.9, then you can just do `python3.9 -m venv venv` and that will create a virtual environment called `venv` with python version 3.9.x.

You can reinstall your libraries there and try running your code again and it will run on 3.9.x.

Comment: Looking at the stacktrace, it looks like seaborn is not installed in your virtual environment. If thats the case, you can just try to install seaborn in your virtualenv with pip.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think I made myself clear. I have my virtual environment created in python 3.8.12, the first task that is performed when I start running the azure function is the installation of libraries in the environment that is done successfully, however, when it continues running the azure function reaches a point where it does not use that environment but the 3.9.7 so it appears as my libraries are not installed, but this is because it is not taking the virtual environment that I am creating.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't take this environment and I have already tried to change it using ctrl+shift+P -> Python Interpreter and selecting the virtual environment that has the libraries installed, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I dont understand how the azure function switches to python 3.9.7 env. If you configure it to run in python 3.8.12 it will always run in python 3.8.12 and not in 3.9.7. If the azure function runs another program in a different server, only then you colud see the scenario you mentioned. In that case you would have to declare seaborn as a dependency in the server where the code runs, not in your local

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have 2 versions of python installed for 2 different projects, 3.10.11 and 3.11.1. However, 3.10.11 was used for creating the virtual env in the azure func project. When I activate my virtual env and did `python -V`, I could see the version is 3.10.11.

When I tried starting the azure function app, it reported "Found Python version 3.11.1 (py)" which is not correct.

I did the following to fix the problem:

1. Delete the old .venv `rm -rf .venv`
2. Created a new .venv (like you just pulled the func app off remote)  `python -m venv .venv`
3. activated virtual env`source .venv/Scripts/activate`
4. reinstalled packages in venv `pip install -r requirements.txt`

or combined:

`rm -rf .venv && python -m venv .venv && source .venv/Scripts/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt`